# How to store list objects into array using angularjs or javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I try to use parse the data from the server and exactly I got result but my issue I want them to store them into a array, I used .push function but it returning only a number of items and not the data from the list of objects.

I used this:

```
var results = [];

return results.push(listOfObject);
```

**from**:

```
angular.forEach(data.Value, function(items) { 
  console.log(items);
  return items; 

  return true;
});
```

**results**:

```
{Id: null, Name: "Innova"}
{Id: null, Name: "Ferrari"}
{Id: null, Name: "BMW"}
{Id: null, Name: "Toyota"}
{Id: null, Name: "Honda"}
{Id: null, Name: "Hyuindai"}
{Id: null, Name: "Kia"}
{Id: null, Name: "Suzuki"}
```

I want to achieve like this:

```
Results: [
   0:{Id: null, Name: "Innova"}
   1:{Id: null, Name: "Ferrari"}
   2:{Id: null, Name: "BMW"}
   3:{Id: null, Name: "Toyota"}
   4:{Id: null, Name: "Honda"}
   5:{Id: null, Name: "Hyuindai"}
   6:{Id: null, Name: "Kia"}
   7:{Id: null, Name: "Suzuki"}
]
```

Comment: Please show the contents of `listOfObject`. You want an array, but what format is the data currently in?

Comment: {Id: null, Name: "Innova"}
{Id: null, Name: "Ferrari"}
{Id: null, Name: "BMW"}
{Id: null, Name: "Toyota"}
{Id: null, Name: "Honda"}
{Id: null, Name: "Hyuindai"}
{Id: null, Name: "Kia"}
{Id: null, Name: "Suzuki"}

Comment: Please edit the question. So you are saying that your data is a single string?

Comment: i dont know what exacatly do you want in here. what do you meant by only a number of items. it does return data from the list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Your achievement is against an Array definition.**
Use Hash object (key-value pair) instead,

I am assuming your data.Value looks like below one.

```
data.Value = [
                {Id: null, Name: "Innova"}
                {Id: null, Name: "Ferrari"}
                {Id: null, Name: "BMW"}
                {Id: null, Name: "Toyota"}
                {Id: null, Name: "Honda"}
                {Id: null, Name: "Hyuindai"}
                {Id: null, Name: "Kia"}
                {Id: null, Name: "Suzuki"}
             ];
```

then the solution would be

```
 var results = {};
 var counter = 0;
 angular.forEach(data.Value, function(eachItem) {
       results[counter] = eachItem;
       counter++;
 });
```

It will give you

```
 results = {
                0:{Id: null, Name: "Innova"},
                1:{Id: null, Name: "Ferrari"},
                2:{Id: null, Name: "BMW"},
                3:{Id: null, Name: "Toyota"},
                4:{Id: null, Name: "Honda"},
                5:{Id: null, Name: "Hyuindai"},
                6:{Id: null, Name: "Kia"},
                7:{Id: null, Name: "Suzuki"}
           }
```

if you want end result to be an array, push this to an array

```
var resultInArray = [];
resultInArray.push(results);

[
   {
                0:{Id: null, Name: "Innova"},
                1:{Id: null, Name: "Ferrari"},
                2:{Id: null, Name: "BMW"},
                3:{Id: null, Name: "Toyota"},
                4:{Id: null, Name: "Honda"},
                5:{Id: null, Name: "Hyuindai"},
                6:{Id: null, Name: "Kia"},
                7:{Id: null, Name: "Suzuki"}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.yearsExcuete = 0;
             $scope.tempValStore = [];
             for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
               $scope.yearsExcuete = parseInt(2018) + parseInt(i);
               $scope.tempValStore.push({year: $scope.yearsExcuete});  
           }
```

Sample Output

```
{
0: {year: 2018}
1: {year: 2019}
2: {year: 2020}
3: {year: 2021}
4: {year: 2022}
5: {year: 2023}
6: {year: 2024}
7: {year: 2025}
8: {year: 2026}
9: {year: 2027} 
}
```